# Where can I find a treasure chest?

Tags: idlelands

My current quest is:

[image: Helping Aunts: Spend 1,000,000 gold; Touch 25 treasure chests.]

> Helping Aunts
>   Spend 1,000,000 gold.
>   Touch 25 treasure chests.

I don't recall ever seeing a treasure chest, and I don't think I'd be able to recognize one.

**Question**: Where can I find a treasure chest?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [update log on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games/comments/2l5oy2/idlelands_update_2_lotsa_stuff_tm/), they're on the world map, guarded by bosses. The bosses are somewhat tough, but should be beatable.